# Как настроить вывод логов в php.ini Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: php, ubuntu, логирование, php.ini

После изменения параметров в /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini  на:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL

display_errors = On

display_startup_errors = On

error_log = /home/user/work/php-errors.log
```

ошибки не записываються в файл /home/user/work/php-errors.log

мой файл [php.ini](https://codepen.io/discipleartem/pen/KqjQEZ)

Я использую встроеный web-сервер php (php -S localhost:3000).

**Как мне настроить php.ini для вывода логов в файл /home/user/work/php-errors.log ?**

Comment: Может прав недостаточно? Точно есть пользователь user    ?

Comment: @IvanBolnikh пользователь то есть, я специально не писал папку /var/log/ как в гайдах, чтобы без рута обойтись. И как узнать хватает ли прав php ?

Comment: PHP у вас запускается или из под апача или из под php-fpm. И тот и другой процесс работает из под определенного пользователя - можно узнать в настройках из под какого именно. Надо понять хватит ли у этого пользователя прав. Зайди под ним и попробовать что-то написать в лог.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh у меня нет fpm php а php cli (/etc/php/7.0/cli/). Я запускаю php не из под апача. У меня на Ubuntu 1 user.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh если что то все заработало уже, наверно нужно было перезагрузиться ))))