# Как настроить вывод логов php в терминал ? Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, веб-сервер, логирование, terminal

ак настроить вывод логов и ошибок php **в терминал** во **время работы** встроенного веб сервера `php -S`  ? 
OS: ubuntu 16.04

Дубликата нет.

- **мне нужен вывод логов и ошибок в окно терминала во время работы веб сервера php**
(вроде того как это может делать интерпритатор ruby по умолчанию)

Comment: `$ tail -f /путь/к/файлу/с/логом`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как настроить вывод логов в php.ini Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/694246/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-php-ini-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Comment: @alexander barakin и как мне писать команду $ tail -f /путь/к/файлу/с/логом во время работы веб сервера ?

Comment: в терминале. собственно, символ `$` на это и намекает. сам этот символ вводить не надо.

Comment: https://vfl.ru/fotos/803e559617975262.html - как видите - это не реально когда работает веб сервер

Comment: а коману ввывода лога нужно запускать в другом терминале. Или запускать "вебсервер" с & в конце строки. Но тогда возможно, Вам будет не так просто его "остановить".

Comment: @KoVadim в этом и проблема, мне не нужны логи, которые я могу посмотреть из файла (даже это не получаеться https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/694246/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-php-ini-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Comment: в общем, вы бы сначала определились с тем, что вам, собственно, нужно. чтоб не решать «[проблему xy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576)».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вобщем я определился и мой вопрос сверху. И это вы пытаетесь мне навязать ваш ответ "У" вместо ответа "Х"

Comment: Эмм, ну-у, можно системному сборщику логов (Например, rsyslog) сказать, что при поступлении сообщения от Вашего "встроенного веб сервера" - посылать его во все активные tty .

Comment: @nobody напишите подробный гайд как этого достичь и может это мне и подойдет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь автор знаком с подпроцессами (&, disown, nohup) т.к. изложенное требуют минимальных знаний работы в терминале.

Разберу вопрос

> OS: ubuntu 16.04

По умолчанию использует systemd для контроля демонов (запуска сервисов), в вашем случае демон это php (phpd, php-fpm), который лучше всего запустить так:

```
~# systemctl start php-fpm
```

Запустится сервис который не займет весь stdout своими выхлопами.

> ак настроить вывод логов и ошибок php в терминал во время работы встроенного веб сервера php -S ?

Если КАК посмотреть выхлоп php после не стандартного запуска, зная заранее расположение лог файлов:

```
disciple@coffe:~/work/php_test_blog2$ php -S localhost:3000 &
disciple@coffe:~/work/php_test_blog2$ nohup php -S localhost:3000
```

Оба варианта дадут схожий результат, отправят процес (php) на задний плат, освободив тем самым stdin для дальнейших действий.

```
~$ tail -Fn100 /home/disciple/work/php-errors.log
~$ less -F /homedisciple/work/php-errors.log
```

Уже покажет вменяемый результат.

```
tail -Fn100 следовать, не заканчивать чтение файла, а ждать до-записи
less +F тот же эффект, только при использовании пейджера
```

Сам я ни разу не пользовался php но довольно долго работаю под Linux, описанный пример работает для 90% всех приложений написанных для *nix систем.

Советую прочесть документацию по устаноправельнойвке PHP или использовать готовые сборки (LAMP). При правиправельнойльной настойке, все логи должны идти в **/var/log**

---

дополнение 27/07/17

Посмотрите в сторону logrotate, rsyslog, journalctl -> http://lmgtfy.com/?q=logrotate%2C+rsyslog%2C+journalctl

**Ссылки**

- http://php.net/manual/ru/install.unix.php
- https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8
- http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu